# Calling two different Python functions from the same .py in a Shell

Tags: python, shell

I have two different function, one is a `Quicksort()` and the other is a `Heapsort()` algorithm, in the same program called `test1.py`. They get input data from a `.txt` file. When I want to run my program  `test1.py`in a shell I want to choose between them, so that I don't get two different results. My Instructor told us that we need to use `-quick` 
(for Quicksort) and `-heap`(for Heapsort). I am not sure how to do that

Any suggestions?

Comment: This could be done by just reading `sys.argv`, or using the `argparse` module for some robustness. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Ask your instructor for help.